# How to create an automatic "ssh" to a cluster

Tags: ssh, terminal

everyone

I am currently using a cluster, and will connect to it frequently using "ssh". Sometimes I need to open multiple terminals. Thus every time when I need to connection, I have to type "ssh username@cluster.com" and followed by the "password" (I am using the Terminal application on Mac OSX).

I am wondering it there any convenient way to achieve it, such as set up a "command" (e.g. "cluster"), and it will automatically establish the connection between my computer and the cluster. What I only need to do is just type "cluster" when I need the connection.

Cheers
Joe

Comment: You can use JSSH(pragalathanm.github.io/jssh/) to login to multiple machines (either via password or via ssh keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH keys as mentioned above by forresty is probably what you want. Alternatively, if you don't want to set that up you can simply edit your ssh config file. You can find it at ~/.ssh/config or  create it if it doesn't exist. Just type the following information into the file:

```
Host cluster
HostName the.long.host@name.com
User username
```

Now when you want to log into the cluster you just type "ssh cluster" and enter your password. This will also work for scp. If you need to copy something to/from the cluster just use "scp cluster:path/to/file"

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that you need to run the same commands on multiple hosts simultaneously, then take a look at [`clusterssh`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page):

> ClusterSSH is a tool for making the same change on multiple servers at
>   the same time. The 'cssh' command opens an administration console and
>   an xterm to all specified hosts. Any text typed into the
>   administration console is replicated to all windows. All windows may
>   also be typed into directly.

If, on the other hand, the issue is that you want to avoid having to type in the password each time you connect, set up [ssh keys](http://blog.stardothosting.com/2009/06/02/ssh-key-based-authentication/).

Lastly, to create an alias for a command on Unix-type systems one can either use [`alias`](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) or write a shell script. This can, for example, be used to shorten a command.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to set up SSH Keys.

As stated on this nice [SSH Keys page on Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys):

> By using SSH Keys (a public and private key to be precise), you can easily connect to a server, or multiple servers, without having to enter your password for each system.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+keys) can be your friend too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the cluster admin tool from : http://sshadmincontrol.com/

```
The Helper MonkeyTool is a portable ssh Java based interface for 
Unix/Linux and MS Windows system administration.integrated with the following 3rd party
tools: Remote Desktop (RDP), PuTTY (included) , WinSCP (included) and Wireshark (separate
download).
```

I"m using the tool to master 2 weblogic clusters with 20 manage servers.